# Apply parser combinator to case class

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm looking at using Scala's [Parser Combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) to parse a string (no newlines, contrived example).

The string is made up of many different parts which I want to extract separately and populate a case class.

```
case class MyRecord(foo: String, bar: String, baz: String, bam: String, bat: String)

object MyParser extends scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers {

  val foo: Parser[String] = "foo"
  val bar: Parser[String] = "bar"
  val baz: Parser[String] = "baz"
  val bam: Parser[String] = "bam"
  val bat: Parser[String] = "bat"

  val expression: Parser[MyRecord] =
    foo ~ bar ~ baz ~ bam ~ bat ^^ {
      case foo ~ bar ~ baz ~ bam ~ bat => MyRecord(foo, bar, baz, bam, bat)
    }

}
```

This works perfectly well, but is there a way to apply the parts of the matched results directly to the case class without deconstructing?

```
val expression: Parser[MyRecord] =
  foo ~ bar ~ baz ~ bam ~ bat ^^ MyRecord
```

*Further information:* The string I'm parsing is quite long and complex (in reality, it's a whole file full of long complex strings) so changing to regexp is out of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with [Shapeless2](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) library. For given:

```
 object MyParser extends scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers   
 import MyParser._     

 val foo: Parser[String] = "foo"
 val bar: Parser[String] = "bar"
 val car: Parser[String] = "car"

 case class Record(f: String, b: String, c: String)
```

You can combine parsers using generic `foldRight` intead of `~`:

```
 import shapeless._
 object f extends Poly2 { 
  implicit def parser[T, U <: HList] = 
   at[Parser[T], Parser[U]]{(a, b) => 
     for {aa <- a; bb <- b} yield aa :: bb  
   }
 }

 val p: Parser[Record] = (foo :: bar :: car :: HNil)
    .foldRight(success(HNil))(f).map(Generic[Record].from)
```

Result:

```
 scala> parseAll(p, "foo bar car").get
 res50: Record = Record(foo,bar,car)
```

P.S. The problem with built-in scala functionality is that they built `~`-based typed binary tree, which is hard to traverse and flatten to tuple. Shapeless solves this problem - it has it's own `::`-based binary tree called `HList`, it's simmilar but has interesting operations, like convertion to tuples or case classes (probably macro-based). In this example I use `foldLeft` to build Shapeless-hlist and for-comprehension (expands to `flatMap` on parser) to combine parsers as they have monadic nature. In shapeless you have to define `foldLeft`'s handler as set of generic implicits, that can process generic input (like `T` or `U`).

You can reuse my `f` object to combine any parsers in typesafe way (you can combine even different types here - that's fine).

---

Second, less generic, way is:

```
implicit class as2[A, B](t: Parser[A ~ B]){ def ^^^^[T] (co: (A, B) => T) = t map {tt => val (a ~ b) = tt; co(a, b)} }
implicit class as3[A, B, C](t: Parser[A ~ B ~ C]){ def ^^^^[T] (co: (A, B, C) => T) = t map {tt => val (a ~ b ~ c) = tt; co(a, b, c)} }
...
implicit class as21 ...
```

Usage:

```
scala> val p = foo ~ bar ~ car ^^^^ Record
p: MyParser.Parser[Record] = Parser ()

scala> parseAll(p, "foo bar car").get
res53: Record = Record(foo,bar,car)
```

It's not so cool, but doesn't require external libraries.

Comment: Somewhere I've got an implementation of a type class that allows `foo ~ bar ^^ (t => as[MyRecord](t))` syntax—I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: I left the question open for a couple of days to see if any more answers came in. I think I prefer your second answer as it doesn't rely on an external lib. Thanks for your help!